# setting style to typeface in Android

Tags: android, typeface

I am creating a custom `Typeface` object using `create(String familyName, int style)`;
Here I am specifying a style. I will use `setTypeface(Typeface)` for setting this `Typeface`.
Everything works fine.

Now if the user wants to change the style.How should I proceed? 
I did not find any method to set the style. The only option left to me is create a `Typeface` object with the new style.Is there any other way?